# html & CSS - alinhar inputs

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte código em HTML:

```
First Name:<input type="text"  placeholder="First name" name="first_name" required> <br>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="last_name"  placeholder="Last Name" required> <br>
Account Number:<input type="text" name="number"  placeholder="account number" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)" required> <br>
Security Number:<input type="text" name="security_number"  placeholder="security number" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)" required>
```

Tentei alinhar usando `text-align:center;` e não deu certo - veja a foto pf aqui: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMCDl.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possível solução:

```css
.form-container span.input-label{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px; /* width a ajustar */
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
  <span class="input-label">First Name:</span><input type="text"  placeholder="First name" name="first_name" required> <br>
  <span class="input-label">Last Name:</span><input type="text" name="last_name"  placeholder="Last Name" required> <br>
  <span class="input-label">Account Number:</span><input type="text" name="number"  placeholder="account number" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)" required> <br>
  <span class="input-label">Security Number:</span><input type="text" name="security_number"  placeholder="security number" onkeypress="return justNumber(event)" required>
</div>
```